# Dotnetnuke cannot process with port other 80

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have a dotnetnuke application that works well when I am using the default http port (80). But it doesn't work with any other port. That means that it works well if the portal is at http://localhost/app, but it doesn't work at http://localhost:81/app.

I tried with setting

```
<add key="UsePortNumber" value="True"></add>
```

but it still won't work.

I appreciate your help. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: How do you know that it is DotNetNuke that's not working and not a firewall issue (most allow port 80 by default for http)?

Comment: In addition to and as a complement to what @ChrisBD asked, what do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: sorry for my question, when I use default port (80), any link on dotnetnuke menu works well. when I use other port, for ex 81. link on menu points to default port, then I got error, "The server at 192.168.1.102 is taking too long to respond..."

Comment: What web server are you using to display this application?

Answer (score 0):

HOST SETTINGS > Advanced Settings > Friendly Url Settings > **Use Friendly Urls (make it false - unchecked) and update.** 
but you will lose Friendly Urls like: **/home.aspx** it will look like **/Default.aspx?tabid=55**
Also you will have page not found or DNS error when try to update, add, delete modules or when you login to the portal for the first time because DNN will redirect you to port 81 or whatever port you are using.